# relation "account_emailaddress" does not exist - django error

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

I am following this tutorial to integrate social media login to my django project -

http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/

However after completing all the steps, when I try to login using facebook, I get this error

```
relation "account_emailaddress" does not exist
```

I don't understand what has gone wrong as all the DB modifications ran properly without errors.

Thanks in advance for your valuable answers.

### Stacktrace

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: example.com/accounts/facebook/login/token/

Django Version: 1.6.6
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'south',
 'registration',
 'endless_pagination',
 'links',
 'south',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/views.py" in login_by_token
  76.                     ret = complete_social_login(request, login)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/helpers.py" in complete_social_login
  119.         return _complete_social_login(request, sociallogin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/helpers.py" in _complete_social_login
  130.         ret = _process_signup(request, sociallogin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/helpers.py" in _process_signup
  26.                                                        sociallogin)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py" in is_auto_signup_allowed
  121.                     if email_address_exists(email):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allauth/utils.py" in email_address_exists
  85.     ret = emailaddresses.filter(email__iexact=email).exists()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in exists
  515.             return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in has_results
  409.         return bool(compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  786.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  69.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  99.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  53.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /accounts/facebook/login/token/
Exception Value: relation "account_emailaddress" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "account_emailaddress" WHERE UPPER("a...
```

`                              ^

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? Have you set up the Facebook app in the Django admin? You need to make a DB entry with your Facebook app details

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony - I have included the traceback now. Also I had added the Facebook app details in the table 'socialaccount_socialapp_sites'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. the `allauth` uses `account` app which doesn't support migrations as yet. Initially I had run

```
python manage.py migrate allauth.socialaccount
python manage.py migrate allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook
```

Along with this we need to run the `syncdb` to complete the puzzle.

Comment: great..glad it was useful for you!

Answer (score 10):

I think you added library providers after performing the first migration, this leaves pending migrations

run

`python manage.py makemigrations allauth`

and

`python manage.py migrate allauth`

Comment: I believe that adding providers from the library after performing the first migration, this leaves pending migrations